# CALayer position animation on video layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, video, cabasicanimation

In this tutorial I have found how to make an animation CALayer in video: 
 http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

```
CABasicAnimation *animation
=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
animation.duration=3.0;
animation.repeatCount=5;
animation.autoreverses=YES;
// animate from fully visible to invisible
animation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
animation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
animation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero;
[overlayLayer1 addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```

But it does not work when I want to animate the movement of CALayer:

```
animation.keyPath = @"position.x";
```

or

```
animation.keyPath = @"position.y";
```

Is it possible to animate the movement of the CALayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any animations will be interpreted on the video's timeline, not real-time, so you should:

1. Set animations’ beginTime property to AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero rather than 0 (which CoreAnimation replaces with CACurrentMediaTime);
2. Set removedOnCompletion to NO on animations so they are not automatically removed;

Answer (score 0):

Try using this keypath :

```
animation.keyPath = @"transform.translation.x";
```